# Looping over an array of objects on Vuejs template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "games": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "init_date": "2020-02-11T07:47:33.627+0000",
      "players_in_game": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "player": {
            "id": 1,
            "player": "Jack Bauer",
            "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "player": {
            "id": 2,
            "player": "Chloe O'Brian",
            "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "init_date": "2020-02-11T08:47:33.627+0000",
      "players_in_game": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "player": {
            "id": 1,
            "player": "Rome Jones",
            "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "player": {
            "id": 2,
            "player": "Ludacris",
            "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

And for every 'players-in game' I want to show one Player VS the other, let's say:

```
**PLayer 1   VS    PLayer 2**
Jack Bauer         Chloe O'Brian
Rome Jones         Ludacris
```

But can't find the way of doing it properly.
Here the code I put:

```html
<tr v-for="(general, index) in getGamesAll.games" v-bind:key="index">
  <td>Game {{general.id}}</td>
  <td v-for="(gamePlayer, j) in general" :key="j">

    {{general.players_in_game.player.player}}
  </td>
  <td>vs</td>
   <td v-for="(gamePlayer, j) in general" :key="j">
     {{general.players_in_game.player.player}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I already know this is wrong, because I'm looping over the same `players-in_game` reaching to player, but neither of both cases specify which player are inside the object I'm talking about.
How could this be accomplished?

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Seems to me like your iterating your 2nd `v-for` on the wrong object, looks like you should iterate over `general.players_id_game`

Comment: that 's the thing players in game has both players included so how could i iterate once to display one and the a second time to display the second one , having in mind  players in game is an array  of object i do pretend to rip inside a table

Comment: You can `<td v-for="(gamePlayer, j) in general.players_in_game" :key="j">`

Comment: Codepen Example here: https://codepen.io/WIS-Graphics/pen/xxGGvJK

Comment: @LeandroMatilla - This Codepen is not a Vue.js app, that's why it's not working.

Comment: @ZimGil I know, it's just an example to implement in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing was to target the correct node when looping.

In the example, 'general' represents one of the items in 'getGamesAll'.

Once we are in that instance of 'general' we want to do our second loop off of the array at node 'players_in_game'.

Then, instead of looping over the same object twice to represent each row, we would try and figure a way to do it with a single loop.  In the snippet, I'm just using the single td element and conditionally adding in that 'vs' message.

```js
var getGamesAll = {
  "games": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "init_date": "2020-02-11T07:47:33.627+0000",
      "players_in_game": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "player": {
            "id": 1,
            "player": "Jack Bauer",
            "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "player": {
            "id": 2,
            "player": "Chloe O'Brian",
            "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "init_date": "2020-02-11T08:47:33.627+0000",
      "players_in_game": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "player": {
            "id": 1,
            "player": "Rome Jones",
            "email": "j.bauer@ctu.gov2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "player": {
            "id": 2,
            "player": "Ludacris",
            "email": "c.obrian@ctu.gov"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}

new Vue({
el:"#players",
data:{
  getGamesAll: getGamesAll
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<table id="players">
<tr v-for="(general, index) in getGamesAll.games" v-bind:key="index">
  <td>Game {{general.id}}:</td>
  <td v-for="(gamePlayer, j) in general.players_in_game" :key="j">
    {{gamePlayer.player.player}} <span v-if="j<1">vs</span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help Kyle, as well as to Leandro Mantilla

Answer (score 0):

You just can find the players by id like this:

```
function getPlayers(games, playerNumber) {

    const players = games.map(game => { // for each game
        return game.players_in_game.map(players => { // for each player
            if (players.player.id === playerNumber) {
                return players.player;
            }
        }).filter(player => player); // Remove distinct players
    });

    return players; // Return players with id === playerNumber
}
```

```
getPlayers(data.games, 2);
```

Return should be:

[image]

Then your template...

```
<tr v-for="(general, index) in getGamesAll.games" v-bind:key="index">
  <td>Game {{general.id}}</td>

  <td v-for="firstPlayer in getPlayers(getGamesAll.games, 1)">
    {{ firstPlayer.player }}
  </td>

  <td>VS</td>

   <td v-for="secondPlayer in getPlayers(getGamesAll.games, 2)">
    {{ secondPlayer.player }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: just put that function in my computed and apply the logic but throws 'games.map 'is not a function, why could be this for?

Comment: Because games is not an Array. Check that first parameter is the games key

Comment: how can i check that...sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Check if the function getPlayers() at first parameter you are sending getGamesAll.games.

Comment: Or put and console.log or breackpoint in first line of the function getPlayers, like: console.log(games);

Comment: id: 1
init_date: "2020-02-11T17:32:09.459+0000"
players_in_game: Array(2)
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}

Comment: thats what i received  giving me indeed both players and their data

Comment: Just send getPlayers(getGamesAll, 1) and in your function change to const players = games.games.map(....

Comment: if i do that then gives me duplicate  keys